# Update a field in a deeply nested document in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

The MongoDB document structure in question looks like this :

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000062"),
"owner": "1",
"version": "Version 1",
"name": "Test20",
"u_at": ISODate("2014-09-25T20:26:16.140Z"),
"c_at": ISODate("2014-09-25T20:26:16.140Z"),
"canvases": [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000063"),
        "nodes": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000060"),
                "filePathTemplate": "LETSDOEMAIL"
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000061"),
                "filePathTemplate": "LETSDOFACEBOOK"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I am struggling primarily with two things:

1. Searching for a specific node and get only the node back in result. Following is the query I am currently using (after browsing all related SO questions):

   `db.getCollection("coll").find({_id: ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000062")}, {canvases:{$elemMatch:{nodes:{$elemMatch:{_id: ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000060")}}}}})`

   But this gives back the canvas, containing the node searched for, instead of node.

   ```
   {
   "_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000062"),
   "canvases": [
       {
       "_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000063"),
       "nodes": [
           {
               "_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000060"),
               "filePathTemplate": "LETSDOEMAIL"
           },
           {
               "_id": ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000061"),
               "filePathTemplate": "LETSDOFACEBOOK"
           }
           ]
       }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. As a result of above mentioned issue, updating a field in a node document is also a problem. This is the query I have got from other SO questions but to no avail:

   `db.getCollection("coll").update({canvases: {$elemMatch:{nodes:{$elemMatch:{_id: ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000060")}}}}}, {$set: {"canvases.$.nodes.$.filePathTemplate": "21"}})`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well in this case since I am using [elemMatch projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/), `find()` returns  the canvas containing matched node, not entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1:

Only the first `$elemMatch` in the second parameter of `.find(arg1, arg2)` is effective to position element of array, that is, only one element of `canvases` can be positioned, excluding `nodes'`. So `.find()` is improper to do this kind of task in my opinion.
But I think you can reach the target by following method:

```
db.coll.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        _id : ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000062")
    }
}, {
    $redact : {
        $cond : [ {
            $or : [ {
                $gt : [ "$canvases", [] ]
            }, {
                $gt : [ "$nodes", [] ]
            }, {
                $eq : [ "$_id", ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000060") ]
            } ]
        }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE" ]
    }
} ]);
```

## Question 2:

- Positional operator `$` can not use in nested array;
- So when you use `$` after an array, all the rest of path must be "solid"; it means if there are nested array behind `$`, you must explicitly write out its index to point out which element you want to update.

Suppose all `_id` in all document level of this collection is unique.
Following code for your reference:

```
var searchKey = ObjectId("54247a68fab6b6775d000060");
var filePathTemplate = "21";

db.getCollection("coll").find({
    canvases : {
        $elemMatch : {
            nodes : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    _id : searchKey
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "canvases.$" : 1
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    // We need to find out the index of that sub-document which is required to
    // updated in nodes, because nodes is probably very big.
    var i = 0;
    var nodes = doc.canvases[0].nodes; // Only one element in canvases from abover query.
    for (; i < nodes.length && nodes[i]._id.str != searchKey.str; ++i);
    var key = "canvases.$.nodes." + i + ".filePathTemplate"; // Only one "$" can be used.
    var updateNodePart = {};
    updateNodePart[key] = filePathTemplate;

    db.getCollection("coll").update({
        canvases : {
            $elemMatch : {
                nodes : {
                    $elemMatch : {
                        _id : searchKey
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $set : updateNodePart
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess you are right. I also tried many combinations but there doesnt seem to be a way to anchor an element in a deeply nested array.